# Implement DTLS Handshake with Philips Hue Bridge using iOS Swift Network Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, network-programming, philips-hue

I'm having trouble with implementing a handshake with a Philips Hue Bridge for home light automation app. The problem lies with my implementation of Apples Network framework. I don't know how to use it basically :) and this is the first time I have tried networking that isn't http. URLSession I am ok with.

I'm guessing my main problem is that I have generated a PSK (See Client Key Example) but I haven't converted it to binary and passed it to the framework somehow. I kind of assumed I didn't need too as I have already generated it with the bridge. I would really appreciate some help.

I have followed these Phillips Hue developer guides:

https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2/

DTLS Handshaking

UDP port 2100 is used for DTLS handshaking and streaming. Only DTLS mode version 1.2 with Pre-Shared Key (PSK) Key exchange method with TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 set as Cipher Suite is supported.

The PSK and PSK identity are provided by the CLIP authentication passing the {“generateclientkey”=true} parameter when push linking your application.

CLIENT KEY EXAMPLE:

```
[
  {
    "success":{
         "username":"myzFXhsLU5Wg10eBithGE-LFikgjC7Q7SEGZsoEf",
         "clientkey":"E3B550C65F78022EFD9E52E28378583"
       }
  }
]
```

The PSK identity exactly matches the CLIP “username” (ASCII / UTF-8 string) from the response.

The PSK is derived from the “client key” in the response by decoding the 32 character ASCII hex string into its 16 byte binary representation. - I'M NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE.

THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE IMPLEMENTED IN MY PROJECT:

```
func connectToHueNetwork(){
    
    let connection = NWConnection(host: "192.168.178.59", port: 2100, using: .dtls)
    
    
    
    connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
        
        switch newState {

        case .ready:
            print("READY")

        case .waiting(let error):
            print("WAITING SERVER ERROR: \(error)\n")
            
            print("DEBUG DESCRIPTION: " + connection.parameters.debugDescription)
            print("CONNECTION STATE: \(connection.state)")
            print("ENDPOINT: \(connection.endpoint)")
            print("PARAMETERS: \(connection.parameters)")

        case .failed(let error):
            print("FAILED SERVER ERROR: \(error)")

        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    connection.start(queue: .main)
}
```

ERRORS:

2021-02-24 14:37:06.432222+0000 TLSHandshake[923:179774] [boringssl] boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(1763) [C2:1][0x106410070] read alert, level: fatal, description: handshake failure
2021-02-24 14:37:06.440314+0000 TLSHandshake[923:179774] [boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(90) [C2:1][0x106410070] SSL library error
2021-02-24 14:37:06.440469+0000 TLSHandshake[923:179774] [boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(41) [C2:1][0x106410070] Error: 4399898168:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-351.40.2/ssl/tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 40
2021-02-24 14:37:06.440581+0000 TLSHandshake[923:179774] [boringssl] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(767) [C2:1][0x106410070] handshake failed at state 12288: not completed
WAITING SERVER ERROR: -9824: Optional(handshake failure)

DEBUG DESCRIPTION: udp, tls, indefinite 
CONNECTION STATE: waiting(-9824: Optional(handshake failure)) 
ENDPOINT: 192.168.178.59:2100 
PARAMETERS: udp, tls, indefinite

Comment: Did you manage to get DTLS streaming working?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't comment much, as I'm still learning Swift but I copied and pasted your code, switched the `NWConnection(host: "192.168.178.59", port: 2100, using: .dtls)` to`NWConnection(host: bridgeIpAddress, port: 2100, using: .udp)` and was returned in the `Ready` state. Now I don't know where to go from here and I also have no idea how to use my `clientKey` within this function

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29916306)